# in R lapply on a named integer

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have the following array `df`

```
      A  B  C  D  E  F  G
[1,]  0 -4 12 33 -4 -1 -4
[2,]  1 -3 13 34 -3  0 -3
[3,]  2 -2 14 35 -2  1 -2
[4,]  3 -1 15 36 -1  2 -1
[5,]  4  0 16 37  0  3  0
[6,]  5  1 17 38  1  4  1
```

The `str` of df is the following:

```
int [1:6, 1:7] 0 1 2 3 4 5  ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:7] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
```

And I would like, for each column, to extract the elements which are bigger than 0 but to leave the column names such as to produce a list. One way to do this is with lapply

```
lapply(df,  function(x) x[which(x > 0)])
```

But has two problems:

1. very slow for many operations (essentially is a loop)
2. doesn't always produce a list, which is necessary to me (if all the original elements are by chance all positive, it will leave it as is).

Is there a better solution than `lapply`?

Comment: do you have a matrix?

Comment: The above is a named integer but I guess can be transformed to a matrix

Comment: an integer (vector) has 1 dimension

Comment: Please provide `dput(df)`. What you show there appears to be a matrix.

Comment: please post the result of `class(df)` i bet its a matrix.

Comment: Your instruction is wrong, it should throw an error. It seems you want `apply`, not `lapply`.

Comment: int [1:6, 1:7] 0 1 2 3 4 5  ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:7] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...

Comment: Please put the full output into the question. But it is a matrix. Anyway, you can't do better than `lapply(as.data.frame(m), function(x) x[x > 0])`.

Comment: @Rui is right, I miss-copied, lapply doesnt need the 2

Comment: When you use lapply on a matrix it evaluates CELL-wise not COLUMN-wise.